# How to cal external json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I created a bootstrap menu and submenu from json data whic is currently cal from variable. The menu submenu working properly. How to cal same data from external json.

```js
var data = {
    "menu": [
        {
            "MenuId": 1,
            "MenuName": "My Transactions",
            "SubText": "Loan Processing",
            "Dropdown":"caret",
            "MenuLink": "#",
            "LinkClass": "dropdown-toggle",
            "DataToggle": "dropdown",
            "Action": null,
            "Controller": null,
            "ParentID": null,
            "SortOrder": 1,
            "ModuleId": null,
            "Menus": [
                {
                    "MenuName": "Loan Eligibility",
                    "MenuId": 2,
                    "MenuLink": "LoanGettingStarted.aspx",
                    "ParentID": 1,
                    "SortOrder": 1,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "Invoice upload",
                    "MenuId": 3,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 1,
                    "SortOrder": 1,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MenuId": 4,
            "MenuName": "My Apps",
            "SubText": "Customized Workflows",
            "Dropdown": "caret",
            "MenuLink": "#",
            "LinkClass": "dropdown-toggle",
            "DataToggle": "dropdown",
            "Action": null,
            "Controller": null,
            "ParentID": null,
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "ModuleId": null,
            "Menus": [
                {
                    "MenuName": "My Lead",
                    "MenuId": 5,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 4,
                    "SortOrder": 1,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "Payment Details",
                    "MenuId": 6,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 4,
                    "SortOrder": 2,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "Extended Warranty",
                    "MenuId": 7,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 4,
                    "SortOrder": 3,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "COI",
                    "MenuId": 8,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 4,
                    "SortOrder": 4,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "S2S Lead",
                    "MenuId": 9,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 4,
                    "SortOrder": 5,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MenuId": 10,
            "MenuName": "Performance Report",
            "SubText": "Intract, Contribute",
            "Dropdown": "caret",
            "MenuLink": "#",
            "LinkClass": "dropdown-toggle",
            "DataToggle": "dropdown",
            "Action": null,
            "Controller": null,
            "ParentID": null,
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "ModuleId": null,
            "Menus": [
                {
                    "MenuName": "Trade Advance",
                    "MenuId": 11,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 10,
                    "SortOrder": 1,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "DDF",
                    "MenuId": 12,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 10,
                    "SortOrder": 2,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MenuId": 13,
            "MenuName": "Service Desk",
            "SubText": "Raise, Resolve & Track",
            "Dropdown": "caret",
            "MenuLink": "#",
            "LinkClass": "dropdown-toggle",
            "DataToggle": "dropdown",
            "Action": null,
            "Controller": null,
            "ParentID": null,
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "ModuleId": null,
            "Menus": [
                {
                    "MenuName": "Customer Service",
                    "MenuId": 14,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 13,
                    "SortOrder": 1,
                },
                {
                    "MenuName": "Retailer Helpline",
                    "MenuId": 15,
                    "MenuLink": "#",
                    "ParentID": 13,
                    "SortOrder": 2,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MenuId": 16,
            "MenuName": "Update",
            "SubText": "Communication",
            "MenuLink": "LoanGettingStarted.aspx",
            "LinkClass": null,
            "DataToggle": null,
            "Action": null,
            "Controller": null,
            "ParentID": null,
            "SortOrder": 5,
            "ModuleId": null,
            "Menus": {
            }
        }
    ]
};

$(function () {
    for (var key in data.menu) {
        var root_menu = data.menu[key];
        if (root_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
            $("#menu").append('<li class="dropdown"><a href="' + root_menu.MenuLink + '" class="' + root_menu.LinkClass + '" data-toggle=' + root_menu.DataToggle + '>' + root_menu.MenuName + '<span class="' + root_menu.Dropdown + '"></span> <br /> <span style="font-size:smaller">' + root_menu.SubText + '</span>' + '</a></li>');
            if (root_menu.hasOwnProperty("Menus") && root_menu.Menus.length > 0) {
                $("#menu li:last").append("<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' id='menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + "'>");
                if (root_menu.Menus.length > 0) {
                    for (var mkey in root_menu.Menus) {
                        var sub_menu = root_menu.Menus[mkey];
                        $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId).append("<li><a href='" + sub_menu.MenuLink +"'>" + sub_menu.MenuName + "</a></li>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu"></ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by external JSON ?

Comment: That depends on where exactly that external JSON is stored and how.

Comment: Its store in same location like $.getJSON('menu.json', function (data) { }); or how to cal from ajax..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sagar, you can simply use `$.getJSON()` method in `jQuery` to perform an `AJAX` call to your external `JSON` file and later iterate through it using `$.each()` method.

**Example**

---

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgkYrpeouq?indent=2", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, field) {
    //$("div").append(field + " ");
    console.log(field);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I modified for loop to each function.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to request a JSON via HTTP you can either use [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), as you already include jQuery, or [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is a newer vanilla JS approach.

If you're unfamiliar with it I'd suggest you read the docs first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to load json data from string?
If that is the case, use JSON.parse()

<s>here's better explanation.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp</s>

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. well, I don't use that site usually, but just came up to the top of google result, so.. well, good to know. thanks.

Comment: No problem. That's the issue with their site really, they appear very highly in Google searches even though they spread inaccurate information.